# php mongo upsert issue

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm using this package https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#mongodb-specific-operations to deal with a mongo on the project I'm working on.

I have collection with such a structure (here is a example of one document)

```
 { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fda3a602279e5262a3ddec6"), 
        "type" : "type", 
        "tags" : [
            "tag1", 
            "tag2",
        ], 
        "filters" : [
            {
                "key" : "1", 
                "label" : "some key1"
            }, 
            {
                "key" : "2", 
                "label" : "some key2"
            }
        ], 
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-12-16T16:48:32.000+0000"), 
        "created_at" : ISODate("2020-12-16T16:48:32.000+0000")
    },
```

what I need to do is check if collection has a document with a same type and exact same tags as provided, if yes I need to update that document if not create it.

Here is a code I wrote:

```
     $this->collection->where('type', $type)
            ->where('tags', 'all', $tags)
            ->update(
                ['type' => $type, 'tags' => $tags, 'filters' => $filters,],
                ['upsert' => true,]
            );
```

here I'm checking if we have a document with a type equal to `$type` and tags same as `$tags`, if such document exists I update it (replace all data with a new one) if not it should create a new document, thanks to `['upsert' => true,]`

But when I'm running it I'm getting error `cannot infer query fields to set, path 'tags' is matched twice`

FYI: when I'm removing `->where('tags', 'all', $tags)` query is working, not sure if correct, but it's not failing

Also I tried to do it like this: `->where('tags', ['$all' => $tags])` and issue is the same as above

**Updated** it's happening only when it trying to insert new field, updates work correctly

Comment: Where is the documentation for the operations you are using and what does it say is the correct usage?

Comment: here is a documentation of  `all `usage in php libray - https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#mongodb-specific-operators. Here is the usage php usage of upsert - https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#mongodb-specific-operations . Here is a mongo documentation about `all` - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/, and here is for upsert - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/ (search for upsert keyword)

Comment: `all` doesn't do an array equality match, it checks that each of the elements in the query is in the document array.  It will also match if the document's array contains additional elements.